# how to overwrite duplicated keys from dictionary list in odoo

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, odoo

I'm working product summary report for POS orders, I make a method that loop over all pos order lines and retrieve data from there, the final result should be unique product name but with the sum of sold quantities, I did it, but the output returns non-unique products and the length of the list is the summation of the order lines, I need  to remove all duplicated product and set only the last one which has the maximum quantity, here is the code

```
@api.multi
def product_summary_test(self):
    product_summary_dict = {}
    data = []
    if self.date_from and self.date_to:
        order_detail = self.env['pos.order'].search([('date_order', '>=', self.date_from),
                                                     ('date_order', '<=', self.date_to)])
        if order_detail:
            for each_order in order_detail:
                for each_order_line in each_order.lines:
                    if each_order_line.product_id.name in product_summary_dict:
                        product_qty = product_summary_dict[each_order_line.product_id.name]
                        product_qty += each_order_line.qty
                        res1 = {
                            "name": each_order_line.product_id.name,
                            "sold_qty": product_qty,
                        }
                        data.append(res1)
                    else:
                        product_qty = each_order_line.qty
                        res2 = {
                            "name": each_order_line.product_id.name,
                            "sold_qty": product_qty,
                        }
                        data.append(res2)

                    product_summary_dict[each_order_line.product_id.name] = product_qty;
    if data:
        print(len(data))
        print(data)
        return data
    else:
        return {}
```

the print for testing purpose, how can I do that ??

Comment: `It is best to think of a dictionary as a set of key: value pairs, with the requirement that The keys are unique (within one dictionary)` as you can read at [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). Why do you think that you have duplicate product names in a dictionary?

Comment: the output is a list of dictionaries, every dictionary has its unique keys but I need  to make it unique over the list also

Comment: Instead of adding a dictionary in each loop, you can convert `product_summary_dict` to a list of dictionaries outside the for loop which should be unique.